# Using RubyMine 5 with a Virtual Machine

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine, rubymine

I just got `RubyMine 5.0.2`, it's supposed to support `Virtual Machines`.
I have `VMware Player` with `CentOS` installed and `RubyMine 5.0.2` installed in `Windows 8`.

When I create a new project with the path `\\\192.168.118.165\MyProjectRoot`, I get a message `"The directory \\\192.168.118.165\MyProjectRoot is not empty. Would you like to create a project from existing sources instead?"` I answer `yes`.

Then in the project tab I can see the `root` files such as `"Readme", "Gemfile", "config.ru"`...
But I can't see any folder. The Structure tab is empty too.
If I go to `files`>open directory , select `\\192.168.118.165\MyProjectRoot`, nothing is imported.

Thanks for your help

Comment: UNC paths are not supported by RubyMine, you need to either sync from the remote to local if you have an existing project, or create a new project locally and then configure deployment and synchronization with the remote. RubyMine supports remote Ruby interpreters so you'll be able to run and debug the code on the VM, but all the project files must be kept locally and synced when needed (automatic upload of changes is supported).

Comment: @CrazyCoder do you know when UNC paths will be supported?

Comment: It's not in the roadmap, follow http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2491 for progress.